# T-SQL how to count the number of duplicate rows then print the outcome?

Tags: t-sql, variables, count, row

I have a table ProductNumberDuplicates_backups, which has two columns named ProductID and ProductNumber. There are some duplicate ProductNumbers. How can I count the distinct number of products, then print out the outcome like "()  products was backup." ? Because this is inside a stored procedure, I have to use a variable @numrecord as the distinct number of rows. I put my codes like this:

```
set @numrecord= select distinct ProductNumber
from ProductNumberDuplicates_backups where COUNT(*) > 1
group by ProductID
having Count(ProductNumber)>1
Print cast(@numrecord as varchar)+' product(s) were backed up.'
```

obviously the error was after the = sign as the select can not follow it. I've search for similar cases but they are just select statements. Please help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select @numrecord= count(distinct ProductNumber)
from ProductNumberDuplicates_backups 
Print cast(@numrecord as varchar)+' product(s) were backed up.'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
begin tran
create table ProductNumberDuplicates_backups (
    ProductNumber int
)

insert ProductNumberDuplicates_backups(ProductNumber)
    select 1 
    union all
    select 2
    union all
    select 1
    union all
    select 3
    union all 
    select 2

select * from ProductNumberDuplicates_backups

declare @numRecord int

select @numRecord = count(ProductNumber) from 
    (select ProductNumber, ROW_NUMBER() 
        over (partition by ProductNumber order by ProductNumber) RowNumber
from ProductNumberDuplicates_backups) p
where p.RowNumber > 1

print cast(@numRecord as varchar) + ' product(s) were backed up.'
rollback
```

Comment: Thanks, but the print line is showing 28 products, which is 4 more than what I actually expected.``